# Login to google account

Tags: php, redirect

I want to login to my google account and then I want to redirect to a specific [url](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/v2/statistics/download?package=?&sd=?2&ed=?&dim=overall,country,language,os_version,device,app_version,carrier&met=active_device_installs,daily_device_installs,daily_device_uninstalls,daily_device_upgrades,active_user_installs,total_user_installs,daily_user_installs,daily_user_uninstalls,daily_avg_rating,total_avg_rating&dev_acc=?). I want to do that in order to retrieve the csv file with the statistics. So my question is how can I login and redirect to the aforementioned url? I want this take place on the backend, I don't want to provide username and password because this will always be the same. I've used the code below to login but I take the following response

```
<?php

require 'openid.php';
try {
  $openid = new LightOpenID('https://www.google.com');
  if (!$openid->mode) {

    $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
    $openid->required = array('namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last', 'contact/email');
    header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    if ($openid->validate()) {
        echo 'User <b>' . $openid->identity . '</b> has logged in.<br>';

        echo "<h3>User information</h3>";

        $identity = $openid->identity;
        $attributes = $openid->getAttributes();
        $email = 'alexdowining@gmail.com';
        $first_name = 'Alex';
        $last_name = 'Dowining';

        echo "mode: " . $openid->mode . "<br>";
        echo "identity: " . $identity . "<br>";
        echo "email: " . $email . "<br>";
        echo "first_name: " . $first_name . "<br>";
        echo "last_name: " . $last_name . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo 'User ' . $openid->identity . 'has not logged in.';
    }
}
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

 ?>
```

1. That’s an error. The service you requested is not available at this time. Service error -27. That’s all we know.